# How to check <p> value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check `<p>` value in jquery condition but it is not working.

I have add a value to `<p>` on one particular condition. They I need to check that value another condition if the value is the same make it empty. but checking condition is not working

```
if($(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(9)").find("p").text()=='N/A') 
       $(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(9)").find("p").text("");
```

Comment: What does `$(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(9)").find("p").length` give you?  If it's `0` (most likely) then your selector is wrong.  Without seeing any HTML at all, can't really help you beyond that (maybe `nth-child(8)` if you've mixed up 0-based and 1-based)

Comment: what do you mean 'it's not working'. do you get any errors?

Comment: If you set the `"N/A"` via anything other than `.text("N/A")` (eg when first rendering the page) then it'll likely have whitespace - so you'll need to use `.text().trim()`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it is showing `0`. Why? value is there `N/A`

Comment: Your selector is wrong... no DOM elements was found... without HTML we can't know why.

Comment: If it's `0` then: **your selector is wrong**.  I believe I already answered that question.  It's not the check for "N/A", that's not a `selector`, it's the `.ms-formtable tr:nth-child(9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the contents of an element using the `$().text()` method:

https://jsfiddle.net/80gjLtba/2/

If there is white space before or after the text you are checking for in the element, you will need to trim the string first for your comparison to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/80gjLtba/4/

It is also possible that your check fails because your selector does not match. You can detect that case by checking the .length property of your jQuery result:

https://jsfiddle.net/80gjLtba/6/